# Is the "down beat" quaver note in a swing piece the same length as a crotchet triplet?

Tags: sheet-music

In 4/4 time, when 8th notes are swung the 1st quaver in the beat becomes longer than the second quaver and depending on how much the piece is swung the second quaver gets shorter as the 1st quaver of the beat gets longer. If a piece is swung at 100% by definition, or at least the way I have understood it, the 1st quaver is now twice as long as the second quaver of the beat and in my DAW when I set this up I also notice that the 1st quaver becomes exactly as long as a crotchet triplet. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, yes, in reality, seldom. For written purposes, it works. Some research has been done on tunes and players that swing, and it's been found that it's not 66/33, but, from memory, maybe 62/38 or thereabouts. And the proportions vary between faster and slower songs. Looked it up - can't locate it. That would be pretty difficult to write on the staves!

What it's *not* is a dotted crotchet followed by a quaver. That's taking the proportions too far: 75/25.

That apart, I believe it's not an exact proportion throughout a song, or indeed from player to player. Big question is - if it was an exact proportion, how could it be written?

EDIT: Google 'Can this even be called music?' for an interesting explanation of 'swing feel'.

Comment: That is kind of confusing but I get it. It is also worth mentioning that 1 quaver triplet is also equal to the second quaver of the beat. This is like saying  a quaver can also equal 1 quaver triplet. A bit crazy but hey if it works :)

Comment: It's way too early to accept this answer! But it's always going to be a thorny question (+1) as it's far more a feel thing than anything mathematical. And - I don't believe it's that easy for a single player to swing - much more effective with a section. But that's not going to happen all the time. When it does, it's *in the pocket*.

Comment: You may be getting confused by a setting in some particular sequencer program that defines a 66/33 ratio as '100% swing'.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - can't be that. I don't go that deeply into that sort of stuff. Programs?  Nevertheless, I'm still convinced that swing is using 66/33 at least as a start point. 12/8 *is* that, at least technically.

Comment: 'Swing' CAN embrace triplets, but not I think as a mean.  The notation programs (Sibelius, Finale etc.) that recognise 'Swing' as a playback instruction don't default to a triplet feel.  Sibelius offers 61.3-38.7% as 'Swing' (actually it's counting 'clicks', 157:99, hence the funny percentage figures.)  'Light Swing is 57-43%.   And yes, there's a 'Heavy Swing' at 68-32% and a 'Triplet swing' at 66-34% (close enough!)